# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION with Sikuli's openApp method

Tags: java, batch-file, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am using [Sikuli-api](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) to automate a standalone application. This application starts on running `*.bat` file. In code I am opening this application as:

```
 m_sikscr=new SikuliScript();
    m_sikscr.openApp("path of bat file");
```

I am getting below exception on this openApp() command.

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x515ee11e, pid=3992, tid=5868
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-x86 )
```

**Whereas, when I try to open same bat file via below line of code, it gets open successfully.**:

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "*.bat"};
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = r.exec(command);
     p.waitFor();
```

**Below is stack trace** :

```
Stack: [0x00d50000,0x00da0000],  sp=0x00d9edc8,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xce11e]
C  [Win32Util.dll+0x147d]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.sikuli.script.Win32Util.openApp(Ljava/lang/String;)I+0
j  org.sikuli.script.App.open()Lorg/sikuli/script/App;+19
j  org.sikuli.script.App.open(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/sikuli/script/App;+8
j  org.sikuli.script.SikuliScript.openApp(Ljava/lang/String;)I+1
j  testpack.OmsTest.openOMS()V+1509
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I am failing to understand if it is an issue with bat file or Sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you show, sikuli  calls into native code, where Win32utils fails. This is how Java reports Crashes in C code.

You most likely forgot some configuration bit.

Comment: I set `JPARAM=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` environment variable, as got some hint from [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/2220). For now , `openApp()` method not crashing the JVM. But I am not sure if JPARAM environment variable did the trick. (not that experienced in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue with openApp() but on OS X. As workaround i use old versiom Sikuli (1.0.1).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1498949

Comment: Thank you for sharing the bug. As I commented on below answer, I set JPARAM env. veriable. Do you think it would have solved the problem? Since JVM is not crashing on openApp method.